# Why Initializing References to Null Is allowed In Java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, null, initialization

In the following example that uses JDBC (this question though is not specific to JDBC):

```
Connection conn = null;

try
{
  ..... Do the normal JDBC thing here  ....
}
catch(SQLException se)
{
   if(conn != null)
   {
     conn.close();
   }
}
```

If I do not initialize the `conn` to `null` then the compiler complains that in the `catch` block I cannot use a reference that has not been initialized.

Java by default initializes a object reference to null then why do I need to explicitly initialize it to null. If the compiler did not like the original value of the reference which was null to start with , why did it  even accept my explicit initialization?

NOTE: I am using `Eclipse Luna` as my IDE.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: At the time of asking this question (with the knowledge that I had) the title made proper sense to me. In hindsight of course .... :)

Comment: You should close connection in the **finally** block, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will only initialize a variable to null in the class scope.  You are in a method scope so you must explicitly initialize the variable to null.

If the variable is defined at the class level then it will be initialized to null.

Comment: makes sense . In a method scope what value does Java give it on its own? Is it some unknown garbage value ?

Comment: Note that it's not initializing an *object* - it's initializing a *variable*. They're very different things.

Comment: agreed!! its initializing the reference to the object.

Comment: @davison: it doesn't give it any value of its own, since it forces you to explicitely initialize it.

Comment: @davison It doesn't give it *any value* in local scope. It insists that *you* do, otherwise it won't compile the code.

Comment: To put it another way: if it is an object field it will get default value if not assigned explicitly. If it is a variable declared within a method you have to provide explicit initialisation.